# 404 Error regarding unrapping KMS Crypto key

Tags: google-cloud-kms

Seeing the following error when attempting to unwrap KMS key. Key ring exists in us-east1

```
google.api_core.exceptions.NotFound: 404 Received the following error message from Cloud KMS when unwrapping KmsWrappedCryptoKey "projects/PROJECT_ID/locations/us-east1/keyRings/KEYRING_NAME/cryptoKeys/KEY_NAME": The request concerns location 'us-east1' but was sent to location 'global'. Read go/storky-stubby for more information.
```

Comment: "Did you follow the steps for [importing keys](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/importing-a-key), Were you trying to import a key to US-east1 but ended up sent to Global? or the other way around?"

Comment: Went and ran the key creation & import process over again. Not sure what was missed but working now. Found that using gcloud was a bit more explicit w/ the key details that just the GUI